# function booleana javasvript

Tags: javascript

necesito ayuda con este ejercicio:

```
function estaOffline(usuarios, nombre) {
// La funcion llamada "estaOffline" recibe como argumento un array de objetos llamado 'usuarios' y un string llamada 'nombre'.
  // cada objeto tiene una property 'nombre' que es un string y otra llamada 'online' que es un booleano.
  // La función debe retornar true si el usuario se encuentra offline, de lo contrario false.
  // ej:
  // var usuarios = [
  //     {
  //       nombre: 'toni',
  //       online: true
  //     },
  //     {
  //       nombre: 'emi',
  //       online: true
  //     },
  //     {
  //       nombre: 'agus',
  //       online: false
  //     }
  // ];
  // estaOffline(usuarios, 'agus') retorna true
  // estaOffline(usuarios, 'emi') retorna false
```

Intenté hacer resolverlo pero no termino de entender como debo afrontar el ejercicio. creo que debería hacer un if() pero no se que poner adentro para saber si el usuario está online o no.

Este fue mi intento, sin embargo se que esta mal.

```
for(nombre in usuarios){
  if(this.online=== false){
    return true 
  } else {
    return false 
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Javier, deberías de darte una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) así podrás ganar tu primera medalla. Con respecto a tu pregunta hay cosas que no comprendo... Dicen que hagas una función ¿Pero lo que has intentado no es una función?. ¿A qué hace referencia `this`?¿Si dices tener un error porqué no lo pones? No somos adivinos, la descripción del error sería de gran ayuda .

Comment: hola fran! gracias por el cometario, ya edite el post para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: Ya agregue mi intento Marcos, no lo agregue porque se que esta mal hecho y no tengo manera de comprobar que está mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes buscar con un bucle ForEach y comprobar si esta online y retornar lo contrario. Aqui si no encuentra el usuario te va a regresar null

```js
var usuarios = [
       {
         nombre: 'toni',
         online: true
       },
       {
         nombre: 'emi',
         online: true
       },
       {
         nombre: 'agus',
         online: false
       }
   ];
   
   function estaOffline(usuarios, nombre) {
        let online = null;

            usuarios.forEach(function (o) {
                if (o.nombre == nombre) {
                    online = !o.online; //Regresas lo contrario a online
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return online;
   }
   
   document.write("El usuario toni esta offLine " + estaOffline(usuarios, "toni"));
   document.write("</br>")
    document.write("El usuario emi esta offLine " + estaOffline(usuarios, "emi"));
    document.write("</br>")
     document.write("El usuario agus esta offLine " + estaOffline(usuarios, "agus"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma usando un [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Cuando encuentra una coincidencia, simplemente retornar el valor `e.online` negado. Si el nombre no existe, el `for` terminará y retornará `undefined`, pero puedes cambiarlo a lo que quieras.

```
function estaOffline(usuarios, nombre) {
    for(let e of usuarios) {
        if(e.nombre == nombre) {
            return !e.online;
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola javier!

Bienvenido, en primer lugar. Bueno, comentarte una posible solución al ejercicio que comentas. Lo que puedes hacer es recorrer el array de objetos y comprobar en cada uno de ellos si contiene el nombre que le pasas como parámetro. Muy sencillo. Te explico como lo haría a continuación.

(Utilizo un `for(){}` sencillo, para que sea más fácil de entender)

```
function estaOffline(usuarios, nombre){
    for (var i = 0, max = usuarios.length; i < max; i += 1) {
 
        if(usuarios[i].nombre == nombre){
            return !usuarios[i].online;
        }
    }
}
```

Lo único, para la próxima pregunta, quizás sea bueno que, aunque te parezca poco o una tontería, publiques lo que has intentado. Así podemos decirte en que cosas has hecho bien y que cosas habría que cambiar. De todas formas, ¡espero haber sido de ayuda!

¡Un saludo!